# Odd behavior with using transform function to postprocess AST in order to rename json field name

Tags: json, scala, transform, rename, lift

Chances are that I am doing this wrong, but here goes. I'm using lift-json to turn a json response string into an object. The response string I get has some names for fields that aren't the best idea to use in Scala, i.e. option. I wanted to write a "helper" function that is pretty much just a wrapper around JValue.transform:

```
def renameFields(originalJson : JValue, oldFieldName : String, newFieldName : String): JValue = {
    originalJson transform { case JField(oldFieldName,x) => JField(newFieldName, x)}
}
```

Here is the sample response string and JObject I'm working with:

```
scala> val jstring = """ { "aisle" : 1, "bin" : 1, "hasWhat" : [{ "id" : 4, "name" : "Granny", "color" : "green"}, { "id" : 4, "name" : "Fuji", "color" : "red"}] }"""
jstring: java.lang.String =  { "aisle" : 1, "bin" : 1, "hasWhat" : [{ "id" : 4, "name" : "Granny", "color" : "green"}, { "id" : 4, "name" : "Fuji", "color" : "red"}] }

scala> val json = parse(jstring)
json: net.liftweb.json.JsonAST.JValue = JObject(List(JField(aisle,JInt(1)), JField(bin,JInt(1)), JField(hasWhat,JArray(List(JObject(List(JField(id,JInt(4)), JField(name,JString(Granny)), JField(color,JString(green)))), JObject(List(JField(id,JInt(4)), JField(name,JString(Fuji)), JField(color,JString(red)))))))))
```

If I use this function, all the field names end up getting changed:

```
scala> Util.renameFields(json,"aisle","row")
res2: net.liftweb.json.JsonAST.JValue = JObject(List(JField(row,JInt(1)), JField(row,JInt(1)), JField(row,JArray(List(JObject(List(JField(row,JInt(4)), JField(row,JString(Granny)), JField(row,JString(green)))), JObject(List(JField(row,JInt(4)), JField(row,JString(Fuji)), JField(row,JString(red)))))))))
```

And what I actually want is:

```
scala> json transform { case JField("aisle",x) => JField("row",x) }
res3: net.liftweb.json.JsonAST.JValue = JObject(List(JField(row,JInt(1)), JField(bin,JInt(1)), JField(hasWhat,JArray(List(JObject(List(JField(id,JInt(4)), JField(name,JString(Granny)), JField(color,JString(green)))), JObject(List(JField(id,JInt(4)), JField(name,JString(Fuji)), JField(color,JString(red)))))))))
```

So...what am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

-Still Newbie

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think all you're missing is backticks around `oldFieldName`:

```
scala> def renameFields(originalJson : JValue, oldFieldName : String, newFieldName : String): JValue = originalJson transform { case JField(`oldFieldName`,x) => JField(newFieldName, x)}
renameFields: (originalJson: net.liftweb.json.JsonAST.JValue,oldFieldName: String,newFieldName: String)net.liftweb.json.JsonAST.JValue

scala> val jstring = """ { "aisle" : 1, "bin" : 1, "hasWhat" : [{ "id" : 4, "name" : "Granny", "color" : "green"}, { "id" : 4, "name" : "Fuji", "color" : "red"}] }"""
jstring: java.lang.String =  { "aisle" : 1, "bin" : 1, "hasWhat" : [{ "id" : 4, "name" : "Granny", "color" : "green"}, { "id" : 4, "name" : "Fuji", "color" : "red"}] }

scala> val json = parse(jstring)
json: net.liftweb.json.JsonAST.JValue = JObject(List(JField(aisle,JInt(1)), JField(bin,JInt(1)), JField(hasWhat,JArray(List(JObject(List(JField(id,JInt(4)), JField(name,JString(Granny)), JField(color,JString(green)))), JObject(List(JField(id,JInt(4)), JField(name,JString(Fuji)), JField(color,JString(red)))))))))

scala> renameFields(json,"aisle","row")
res0: net.liftweb.json.JsonAST.JValue = JObject(List(JField(row,JInt(1)), JField(bin,JInt(1)), JField(hasWhat,JArray(List(JObject(List(JField(id,JInt(4)), JField(name,JString(Granny)), JField(color,JString(green)))), JObject(List(JField(id,JInt(4)), JField(name,JString(Fuji)), JField(color,JString(red)))))))))
```

Without the backticks, `case JField(oldFieldName,x)` is saying "bind whatever value I find as the `JField` name to the new variable `oldFieldName`" and thus your original `oldFieldName` variable is shadowed. With the backticks around `oldFieldName`, you're saying you only want to match a `JField` whose name is the value of `oldFieldName`.

Comment: (*insert wall bash here*) D'oh. The curse of missing backticks/frontticks/quotes. Thanks Steve, I would never have thought of using any type of tick or quote in the method.  Out of curiosity, how did you know to do that?

Comment: I think probably it's from reading the http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1332574/common-programming-mistakes-for-scala-developers-to-avoid thread, in particular the "Using identifiers starting with lower case letter in pattern matching" answer mentions backticks.

Comment: Thanks again Steve! That's a very helpful post.